# Looking to adapt this terminal command to block pages, not full websites

Tags: macos, terminal, website, web, parental-controls

I am trying to block a specific page on a website (a Reddit thread) from being accessed on my Mac laptop.  It contains the answers to a mystery game I got for my fiancée, and I want to make sure she doesn't accidentally find it and spoil the game.

I recently found [this tutorial](http://masonsklut.com/how-to-block-websites-on-your-mac-using-terminal/) which is almost exactly what I need, except for one catch: trial-and-error has shown that it only seems to work with full domains (e.g. "reddit.com") rather than specific URLs (e.g. "reddit.com/r/mystery").

Is there a way to adapt this terminal command for use with more specific URLs?  Or, failing that, is there a similar way to permanently block any access to a certain URL from a Mac laptop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, that `/etc/hosts` DNS-name blocking trick only knows about whole server names, not full HTTP URLs.

Comment: Damn.  Alright, well thanks for the confirmation!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look at *[this page](https://superuser.com/questions/393967/block-specific-url-on-web-browsers)* which delves into a similar question. There's a lenghty discussion about a tool called `privoxy` that was used. There is also a reference in one of the responses to `blacklist.action` and `whitelist.action` files but I couldn't find any other references to these. GL.